# Error when I try and use ggbiplot from the library github

Tags: r, github, ggbiplot

I am trying to use the plotting function ggbiplot using this code:

```
  install.packages("devtools")
  library(devtools)
  install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")

  g <- ggbiplot(iris.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, 
            groups = iris[,5], ellipse = TRUE, 
            circle = TRUE)
 g <- g + scale_color_discrete(name = '')
 g <- g + theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', 
             legend.position = 'top')
  print(g)
```

I get the following error:

```
Installation failed: there is no package called ‘R6’
Error in library(ggbiplot) : there is no package called ‘ggbiplot’
```

I am trying to perform some PCA analysis following this demo https://www.r-bloggers.com/computing-and-visualizing-pca-in-r/

Comment: Have you installed the package `R6`?

Comment: when I try to install the R6 package I get this:
'code'> install.packages("R6")
Installing package into ‘D:/Userfiles/gcanuti/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/R6_2.2.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 316707 bytes (309 KB)
downloaded 309 KB

package ‘R6’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘D:\Userfiles\gcanuti\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\file2798214e7b85\R6’ to ‘D:\Userfiles\gcanuti\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\R6’

Comment: Have you attempted the install with admin rights?

Comment: I should have the admin rights. Is there a way to check if I have them?

Comment: After more investigating, the library ggbiplot is in the github repository. When Rstudio tries and installs it, it looks in the Cran repository. How can I force it to look in github?